# What is the definition of Inference?

Tags: inference, terminology

I see Bayesian inference methods or probabilistic inference.

I haven't really found the definition of inference yet. Talking in terms estimation of parameters is really like method specific.

So, what is inference? Does it always mean to infer something from data. What are the approaches to inference.

Comment: I believe this question is too broad and that the wikipedia page will probably be a good start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inference

Comment: @tibl I think asking for a definition of inference is not too broad - though of course a complete exposition would be.

Comment: Statisticians study inference; probablists study implication.

Comment: @DilipSarwate implication means causality right, one thing implies another?

Comment: I am questioning your divide between Bayesian inference and probabilistic inference which seems to suggest that Bayesian inference does not use probability at all. Frequentist statisticians use (maximum likelihood) inference to _infer_ from the fact that a coin turned up Heads $k$ times in $n$ tosses that $p$, the probability of Heads is $\frac kn$. From the same fact, (some) Bayesian statisticians infer that $p$ is $\frac{k+1}{n+2}$. Both inferences do use notions about probability.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks!! One more thing, Maximum a priori estimation vs Max likelihood, are they same ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Statistical inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_inference) is simply

> The process of drawing conclusions about a population on the basis of
>   measurements or observations made on a sample of individuals from the
>   population.

as defined in *Cambridge Dictionary of Statistics* by B. S. Everitt. It is close to the general definition of [inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inference), i.e. "act or process of deriving logical conclusions from premises", or "observation of patterns of facts, to see new meanings and contexts for understanding indirectly" (see also [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inference), or [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inference)). List of all the possible approaches to statistical inference for all the possible statistical problems is unlimited.